# I am having an issue with an json bodyParser issue

Tags: body-parser

```
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
```

The bodyParser in VS Code has strikethroughs.

Rookie here! trying to get a Spotify clone to work. I've been trying to figure out what is going on here and how to fix it. Any insight is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Don't use bodyParser. It is deprecated, and that's why there are strikethroughs. Replace your lines with:

```
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false});
```

I'm assuming you're using express. If not, just type
`npm i express` into your command line and then
`const express = require('express');`
at the top of your file.

or

`npm i @types/express` and `import express from 'express'` if you're using typescript

Comment: OK. I appreciate that. I read that and am just not sure what effect the depreciated version was having on the project. Having other issues.

Comment: @Aelbione what other issues are you having? And the deprecated version wasn't harming your project or anything.

Comment: Hi! I'm also getting this message: "[HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS..." And, the login button briefly shows the search bar I expect than reverts back to just having the login button back in the middle of the screen again. I am playing around with a Spotify clone from a YouTube tutorial I followed along with. Everything looks right syntactically.

Comment: @Aelbione what prompts this signal? I assume you're writing a web app. When does this occur?

Comment: I am playing around with a Spotify clone from a YouTube tutorial I followed along with. Everything looks right syntactically. Oh, and it occurs when I press the Login button or refresh.

Comment: Do you have a link to a github repo?

Comment: Yes. https://github.com/WebDevSimplified/spotify-clone   .... or, do you mean my code? I think you mean my code. I don't have it up yet. No.

Comment: I actually got it to work, then I started messing around with the only pull request, "Implemented a dark mode", and broke it! :)

Comment: @Aelbione please, please, please add your .env file to your .gitignore. you do NOT want to put your sensitive data on the internet

Comment: Yes, I understand. That link is from the producer of the tutorial. I won't upload my code insecurely. Thank you.